# mongoexport does not write any records to json output file

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I have tried to export a json file from MongoDB with mongoexport in the following way:

```
$ mongoexport --db db --collection ds --dbpath ~/db --out ds.json
exported 0 records
Sat Apr 20 23:13:18 dbexit: 
Sat Apr 20 23:13:18 [tools] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Sat Apr 20 23:13:18 [tools] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Sat Apr 20 23:13:18 [tools] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sat Apr 20 23:13:18 [tools] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sat Apr 20 23:13:18 [tools] shutdown: closing all files...
Sat Apr 20 23:13:18 [tools] closeAllFiles() finished
Sat Apr 20 23:13:18 [tools] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Sat Apr 20 23:13:18 dbexit: really exiting now
```

I do not understand why the created json file empty is, because the database actually contains the following data:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.3
connecting to: test
> use ds
switched to db ds
> db.ds.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : "1_522311",
    "chr" : 1,
    "kg" : {
        "yri" : {
            "major" : "D",
            "minor" : "A",
            "maf" : 0.33036
        },
        "ceu" : {
            "major" : "C",
            "minor" : "A",
            "maf" : 0.05263
        }
    },
    "pos" : 522311
}
{
    "_id" : "1_223336",
    "chr" : 1,
    "kg" : {
        "yri" : {
            "major" : "G",
            "minor" : "C",
            "maf" : 0.473214
        },
        "ceu" : {
            "major" : "C",
            "minor" : "G",
            "maf" : 0.017544
        },
        "jptchb" : {
            "major" : "C",
            "minor" : "G",
            "maf" : 0.220339
        }
    },
    "pos" : 223336
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you have a database called `ds`:

```
> use ds
switched to db ds
```

`use ds` switches the current database to the `ds` database (`db` from the shell is just an alias for the current database).

Then, you have a collection called `ds` as well:

```
> db.ds.find().pretty()
```

So, that means you have a `ds` database with a `ds` collection (`ds.ds`).

You should then use the export like this with the `--db` option set to `ds` (assuming the path to the database is correct):

```
mongoexport --db ds --collection ds --dbpath ~/db --out ds.json
```

**3.0+ Update**: `--dbpath` is [unavailable](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#options).

Comment: it doesn't work for me, i still have the same msg "exported 0 records"

Comment: where is this json file located after creation

Comment: @Tmp mongoexpert is not to type in mongoshell. It should be type in bash. so if you give --out (or - o ) with only file name, it'll be create where your terminal is (pwd = present working directory)

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer may don't satisfied the question, but I hope it will help people struggling with **mongoexport does not write any records to json output file**

My problem was that I was using quotes. For example:

```
$mongoexport --db 'my-database' --collection 'my-collection' --out ds.json
```

but the correct query is (without quotes):

```
$mongoexport --db my-database --collection my-collection --out ds.json
```

I discover this when I did a `$mongodump` and it creates a folder with quotes. This was very estrange to me, but I understood that mongoexport interprets the quotes as part of the name. so when I removed it, it workout fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is great, Thanks !!